# spring mockito: when an object containing a list is an argument

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-test, springmockito

The issue is that the list of `ids` within the `pageRequest` object can be in any order. Is there a way to specify that below? The test fails since the `pageRequest` has a list of `ids` in a different order than the one specified below. The "when" clause returns null in that case.

```
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.builder()
                .ids(List.of(serviceId2, serviceId1, serviceId3))
                .build();
 when(client.getServices(eq(pageRequest))).thenAnswer(a -> {.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a custom `ArgumentMatcher` to define the matching logic and then use `argThat` with this `ArgumentMatcher` during stubbing :

```java
@Test
public void test(){
        when(someMock.getSerivce(argThat(pageRequestContainId(List.of(1,4,5,6))))).thenReturn(blablabla);
}

private ArgumentMatcher<PageRequest> pageRequestContainId(List<Integer> ids) {
        return pageReq -> pageReq.ids.containsAll(ids) && pageReq.ids.size() == ids.size();
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: checking size before checking all elements can be faster (for medium-sized to large lists). Probably a non-issue in tests, but still good practice.